# How to print this model data in template Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named `Item` as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
price = models.FloatField()
bargainprice = models.FloatField(default=0)
discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
slug = models.SlugField()
description = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField()
```

I have a model named `Bargain` as follows:

```
class Bargain(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
     )
  item = models.ForeignKey(
    Item,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
     )
  bprice = models.FloatField()
  class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['item', 'user'], name='unique_user_item')
    ]
```

and I am passing this model data in the template "product.html" as follows:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
model = Item
template_name = "product.html"

def get_bargain(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print("this is the user ", self.user.pk)
        return Bargain.objects.filter(item=self.object, user=request.user).first()
```

and I want to access the "bprice" in the template "product.html" so I am doing this on template :

## This is the Bprice :{{ view.get_bargain.bprice }}

but **it shows nothing**, and I also have one object in bargain model named "Bargain object(3) with all necessary values example : user: admin item:mattalicdot bprice:1799 and I am logined with user admin.

can anyone tell me that what is the issue?

Comment: Firstly, your not calling `get_bargin()` in your jinja. You'll need to pass request through to your template if it's not already there, so it should look like `{{ view.get_bargain(request).bprice }}`

Comment: it throws an error " Could not parse the remainder: '(request).bprice' from 'view.get_bargain(request).bprice'
??

Answer (score 0):

Using a detail view, when the view is rendering it passes an object to the context of the page. In your template you should just be able to say `{{ object.attribute_field }}`, where `attribute_field` is the name of the object field that you want to display in your case it would be `object.bprice`, to be able to display the value.